# Custom IBsonSerializer exception thrown in mongodb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I have written a custom `IBsonSerializer` for the `System.Security.Claims.Claim` class, which is very bloated and needs custom deserialization. This works when called as a one-off but I am hitting problems when registering it and calling from Unit tests and getting the dreaded exception "There is already a serializer registered for type Claim".

The problem is, there seems to be no way to check whether a serializer is registered without it creating one! This seems completely wrong to me. If you call `BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer()`, the code calls the `BsonSerializerRegistry.GetSerializer()`, which calls `GetOrAdd()`. In other words, I cannot check and then add my custom serializer without the exception and if I *don't* check, I might get the error if it gets added a second time.

Have I missed something really obvious here? The Unit Tests are called in a multi-threaded process so even though my setup is in Startup.cs and is only generally called once, it is possible to be called in parallel when the unit tests run.

```
lock (serializerLock)
{
    // I can't call the following, otherwise it creates a default serializer
    //if ( BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer<System.Security.Claims.Claim>().GetType() != typeof(MongoClaimSerializer))
    {
         BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new MongoClaimSerializer());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a few options. 1) Wrap the RegisterSerializer call in a try-catch and ignore the exception (dirty but should work).  2) Write a wrapper to encapsulate the BsonSerializer and perform your own checking logic, or 3) refactor how the unit tests are initialized so the registration call won't happen more than once. What test framework are you using?

Comment: XUnit. Most tests call directly into a controller action but some of them run up a web server with the app in it to test returned http headers and the like. I'm not sure how 2 will work since the underlying properties are not public to perform a lower-level query.

Comment: It would only need to provide a surface level encapsulation of BsonSerializer, with it's own Dictionary consisting of registered serializers which it would populate before passing calls to Register() on, and check against instead of calling LookupSerializer()

Answer (score 1):

The following code should provide sufficient encapsulation for the serializer registration and lookups that you'd need.

```
public static class SafeBsonSerializerRegistry
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IBsonSerializer> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type,IBsonSerializer>();

    public static IBsonSerializer<T> LookupSerializer<T>()
    {
         return (IBsonSerializer<T>)LookupSerializer(typeof(T));
    }

    public static IBsonSerializer LookupSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
        if (typeInfo.IsGenericType && typeInfo.ContainsGenericParameters)
        {
            var message = string.Format("Generic type {0} has unassigned type parameters.", BsonUtils.GetFriendlyTypeName(type));
            throw new ArgumentException(message, "type");
        }

        IBsonSerializer serializer;

        if(_cache.TryGetValue(type, out serializer))
            return serializer;
        return null; //Note, this is where the BsonSerializerRegistry would GetOrAdd().
    }



    public static void RegisterSerializer<T>(IBsonSerializer<T> serializer)
    {
        RegisterSerializer(typeof(T), serializer);
    }

    public static void RegisterSerializer(Type type, IBsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        if (serializer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serializer");

        var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
        if (typeof(BsonValue).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            var message = string.Format("A serializer cannot be registered for type {0} because it is a subclass of BsonValue.", BsonUtils.GetFriendlyTypeName(type));
            throw new BsonSerializationException(message);
        }

        if (typeInfo.IsGenericType && typeInfo.ContainsGenericParameters)
        {
            var message = string.Format("Generic type {0} has unassigned type parameters.", BsonUtils.GetFriendlyTypeName(type));
            throw new ArgumentException(message, "type");
        }

        if (!_cache.TryAdd(type, serializer))
        {
            var message = string.Format("There is already a serializer registered for type {0}.", BsonUtils.GetFriendlyTypeName(type));
            throw new BsonSerializationException(message);
        }

        //call to the actual BsonSerializer
        BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(type, serializer);
    }

}
```

What this doesn't do is replace the existing BsonSerializer or underlying BsonSerializerRegistry. It only guarantees the LookupSerializer methods providing the caller used this to register them in the first place.

Let me know if this isn't suitable and I'll get back to the drawing board.

Comment: How would this be injected so that it is used by the Mongo system or would we simply register the items twice and use this object for checking? I have found another workaround using an IBsonSerializationProvider, which doesn't check or error if there is already a provider that does the same thing! I assume it simply adds duplicates to the stack but only the 'top' one would do anything.

Comment: This class does the call into BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer() for you, so providing you register through this class, the underlying Mongo driver will have everything it needs. Consider this as a gateway when registering serializers and checking for them.

Comment: IBsonSerializationProvider appears to be an alternative to my thin wrapper. You'd have to implement an instance of this interface yourself, register your serializer with your provider, then register your provider with the BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(). Then when ever the BsonSerializer checks for a serializer, it treats it's collection of SerializationProviders like a stack and gets the most recently registered one (which should be yours!)

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was instead of calling `RegisterSerializer` to rather call `RegisterSerializationProvider(new ClaimSerializationProvider())` with a new class that will provide the serializer directly to the system during resolution. This doesn't check for duplicates so will not error if in a multi-threaded scenario, `RegisterSerializationProvider` gets called twice. The provider looks like this:

```
public class ClaimSerializationProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="IBsonSerializationProvider.GetSerializer(Type)"/>
    /// </summary>
    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        // We only provide a custom serializer for Claim
        if (type == typeof(Claim))
        {
            return new MongoClaimSerializer();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean little solution to your problem! The only issue I'd have in this use case is that every call to get a serializer of your type results in a new serializer being created. Other than that, that'll work!

Comment: But then in normal use, the code shouldn't be called multiple times since it is in Startup.cs and is locked for access.